# Javascript regex doesn't give error message when it should

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to input the following value "f+11111111111", and my code doesn't display error message. I tried to remove regex2 condition, and then it worked. But how come? It's an AND condition, why does it act like it's an OR operator?

```
function validatePhone()
{
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

var regex1 =/^[\+\d][\s(\-\d][\s()\-\d]{8,}/g;
var regex2 = /\D*(\d\D*){11}/g;

    if (!phone.match(regex1) && !phone.match(regex2)) {
       producePrompt("Error", "comment_phone_prompt");
       return false;
    }
}

function producePrompt(message, promptLocation)
{
    document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
}
```

Comment: regex2 matches your input and you use a negation `!` in the if condition *(that is obviously evaluated as false)*. Since nobody knows what you are trying to do, difficult to help you more.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes, silly mistake. Need to take a break. Thanks. 

UPD: You already helped enough.

Comment: Using `&&` with `!`, both expressions have to fail to match to enter the `if`'s block. When only one fails to match (`true && false`), the overall result is `false`, skipping the block. You probably want to use `||` with `!` instead ("*if either don't match, prompt an error*").

Answer (score 0):

Your second regular expression `/\D*(\d\D*){11}/g` matches the given string `f+11111111111` and therefore the whole condition evaluates to `false`. You can visualise your regular expressions using [regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#%5CD*(%5Cd%5CD*)%7B11%7D).

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but mind that even this string is matched by the second regex: `'f+1dsadsadasda123131231dsdadai-094i-)@)#(@)_(#_!'` Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Second regex matches everything. Single regex is enough.

```
    function validatePhone() {
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

        var regex1 = /^(\+\d)?(\(|-)?\d{3}(\)|-)?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/;
        //match +1-800-123-45678, (555)123-4567, and so on
        if (!regex1.test(phone)){
            producePrompt("Error", "comment_phone_prompt");
            return false;
        }
        return true;//both sides should return
    }
```